# After setup password-less login, I still got permission denied error while running a script to login

Tags: ssh, password-less

I have already setup the password-less login to localhost via ssh, and it works and doesn't need me to enter any password.

```
justinwu@ubuntu:~$ ssh root@localhost
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-110-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

2 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

New release '16.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Tue Mar  7 10:08:22 2017 from localhost
```

But while running one script and it needs to login as root via ssh, it returns the error 'Permission denied (publickey)'.

```
...
  Launching 20 processes.
    Starting test client: 0 Host:  localhost    Workload:      VDI  Workdir: /mnt/share
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I don't know why the script cannot automatically login via root without entering the password.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the ssh part of the script you're running? Is it running as a different user? The password-less login is per user with the ssh keys so if it can't access your user, it won't work

Comment: The user is root, but from the screenshot above, the script will create virtual clients to login localhost via root user. I don't know if the root I specified is different from the root user of the virtual clients. Seems like they're different. Thanks!

Comment: Have you set up ssh keys and things for your root user? You ran the ssh as user "justinwu" and that connected without a password however the root doesn't access the same authentication keys as that user so you need to set that up as well

Comment: I used the command 'ssh-keygen' to generate the key and copy to the host via 'ssh-copy-id root@localhost'. Then I check by using 'ssh root@localhost', it works. Anything I missed? Thanks!

Comment: And you ran those commands as root? If so that sounds fine. I can't tell much more without seeing the script you're running in case it does anything odd during it's ssh attempts

Comment: I used 'justinwu' to run 'ssh-keygen' and 'ssh-copy-id root@localhost' and 'justinwu' is in the admin group. Is it correct?